# How do I put these two equations in slope intercept form? And how would I graph them?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, slope

$x+y=4$

$x-y=2$

Here is my work so far:

$y=4-x$

$y=-2-x$

Answer (score 1):

$x+y=4 x-y=2$ means

$$x+y=4;x-y=2$$
solving wrt $y$

$$y = -x+4;y = x-2$$

$$
...
$$

[image]